# QGIS layout manager has several A4 layouts: export them all to "the same pdf"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

My QGIS layout manager has several A4 layouts.
I would like to export them all to "the same pdf".

I think that by going through the python console it should be possible.
for now I can only print one page....
Here is my code:

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
for layout in manager.printLayouts(): 
      print(layout.name())
      exporter.exportToPdf("F:/44.pdf",QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Here is the return: 0, 1, 0, 2

Only page 2 is exported to PDF

Comment: _"Here is the return : 0,1,0,2"_ : Does that mean you have four layouts ? Does it retrieve the **right** layout names ?

Comment: Hello,
I only have two layers and two layouts.
I know how to export one or other of the layouts, but I would like to export the 2 layouts in 1 single pdf.